# formatted float output with dtype precision

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, format

I have a couple of numpy float arrays with different data types. I would now like to `print` them and include exactly the "right" number of digits in the output. Naive approaches like

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1.0 / 3.0], dtype=np.float64)
print(a)
print('%f' % a[0])

b = np.array([1.0 / 3.0], dtype=np.float16)
print(b)
print('%f' % b[0])
```

print

```
[ 0.33333333]
0.333333
[ 0.33325195]
0.333252
```

which isn't what I want. I could modify the format string à la `%.18f`, but how do I adapt the number of digits to the `dtype`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's built-in `repr()` is designed for that purpose:

```
print('%r' % a[0])
0.33333333333333331

print('%r' % b[0])
0.33325
```

Answer (score 0):

For NumPy float datatypes, the mantissa length is given [in the documenation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html).
With this, one could go

```
def dtype_digits(dt):
    if dt == numpy.float16:
        mantissa = 10
    elif dt == numpy.float32:
        mantissa = 23
    elif dt == numpy.float64:
        mantissa = 52
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Unknown float type')
    significant_digits = mantissa * numpy.log(2) / numpy.log(10)
    return int(significant_digits)
```

and use that like

```
# data = numpy.array(...)
#
fmt = '%%.%de' % dtype_digits(data.dtype)
for x in data:
    print(fmt % x)
```